Tabular alignment with cline
I would like to move the "P(A | B) = " to the same line as the cmidrule, so that the equals sign aligns with the division line. How can I do this?
MWE:
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,openright,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

Lots of words and then a table.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
  \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
  $P(A \mid B) = $ &
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillACapB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
        &
    $P(A \cap B)$ && \\[1em]
   \cline{2-3}\\
&
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
                    \fillB
        \end{venndiagram2sets}
&
    $P(B)$\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Conditional Probability Rule.} 
\label{CondProbRuleFig}
\end{figure}



You're not using \cmidrule in your example, so booktabs isn't at play here.

Ah, yes, that was left over from when I was playing with \cmidrule vs \cline.

Set the left-hand side outside the tabular construction knowing that (by default) tabulars will have a vertically-centred alignment/anchor point; then, some minor adjustment for any alignment can be done using \raisebox.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{venndiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \raisebox{0.25ex}{$P(A \mid B) = {}$}%
  \begin{tabular}{ c c }
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
      \fillACapB
    \end{venndiagram2sets}
    &
    $P(A \cap B)$ \\[1em]
    \hline \\
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
      \fillB
    \end{venndiagram2sets}
    &
    $P(B)$
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Conditional Probability Rule.} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}

I would probably set it differently though, using a display \frac:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{venndiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  $P(A \vert B) 
    = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}
    = \dfrac{
      \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
        \fillACapB
      \end{venndiagram2sets}}{
      \begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
        \fillB
      \end{venndiagram2sets}}$
  \caption{Conditional Probability Rule.} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Use fractions, with a minimum of visual formatting (the amount of negative raising).
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,openright,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\[
P(A \mid B)= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
=\frac{
    \;\begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
      \fillACapB
    \end{venndiagram2sets}\;
}{
  \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t,raise=-0.7ex}
  \;\begin{venndiagram2sets}[tikzoptions={scale=0.5}]
    \fillB
   \end{venndiagram2sets}%
  \end{adjustbox}\;
}
\]
\caption{Conditional Probability Rule.}
\label{CondProbRuleFig}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


